# Theos tweak caused __NSAutoreleaseNoPool() crash

Tags: crash, jailbreak, theos

I was working on a tweak and everything was going fine, but suddenly the app I was hooking into started giving a ton of __NSAutoreleaseNoPool() errors and crashing. Ive removed the tweak, deleted and reinstalled the app, and restarted the device, but I keep getting the same error. Anyone know how to fix this?

This is the code: 
    #import

```
@interface JMOutlineViewController : UIViewController
@end
@interface PostsViewController : JMOutlineViewController
-(void)hideAll;
@end

%hook PostsViewController

-(void)hideAll {
    if ([self.title isEqual:@"Hidden"]) {
        NSLog(@"we are in the hidden tab");
    } else {
       %orig;
    }
}
%end
```

[Here it is on pastebin](http://pastebin.com/4xjp0Q36/)

Comment: return %orig is not right, when the method you hook returns void.

Comment: I fixed it, though its pretty useless for me now that the app doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

```
NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
```

Insert that code after `-(void}hideAll {`
Then at the end of your method do `[pool release]`

Hope this helped

Comment: But that code isnt being executed anymore. I removed the tweak, as well as reinstalled the app. There is nothing modifying the apps code, yet it is still crashing

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling MobileSubstrate? It could be a problem with "the app" you are trying to modify as well?

Comment: Reinstalling MobileSubstrate didnt help. And the app worked fine before, and works on all my other devices